# windows systemcall to identify hungstate

Tags: windows

Is there any windows system call that can identify a hung state, which I would like to put in a script and run it every 5 minutes, if the system is hung state as the network is still good I can go ahead and reboot the machine

Answer (score 0):

If it is in a hung state, your system call will probably fail and it won't be able to identify itself as in a hung state.

You are best off to monitor this from a remote computer, which tests something non-network related, such as a win32 service which is always supposed to be running, or maybe try to access a SMB share. Things like that...

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.

I generally monitor this in Nagios by checking both that the service is running and that the service is responding on the appropriate port (check_tcp to port number).  When the service hangs, the second check generally fails.